# how to calculate width and height of each character in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

What is the best way to calculate the width and height of each character in a span.

Say, the html looks like:

```
 <span style="font-size:12px">Test 100<span>
```

So, one way is to make a dummy span for each character with the span's style and append it to dom and get it's height and width.

Example, using query:

```
 var x = $('<span style="font-size:12px">' + 'T' + '</span'>);
 $('body').append(x); 
 var h = x.height(),  w= x.width();
 x.remove();
```

But this is inefficient. Is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't really get the size of a character, because the amount of space it takes up depends on which characters it is next to.

For example, the characters `A` and `V` next to each other are kerned so that they are closer together than an `A` next to an `A` or a `V` next to a `V`. Putting the same number of characters interleaved takes less space than putting them next to the same characters:

AVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAVAV
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

Comment: This would be true if kerning was turned on. Those lines take up exactly the same space.

Comment: @tom: That depends on what browser you are using, and possibly some other factors, like operating system. I use Firefox in Windows, and there the lines are not the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a span each time, try changing the innerHTML of the span and get its width. This would be much faster and will no trigger a lot of validation.

Give it a try, does it behave faster?