# How to calculate character width from font size.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to calculate the number of characters that fits in one line of a div and trim off the rest although `text-overflow` is an option I rather calculate the length of the string that fits in it properly. Is the font-size of a character almost equal to it's width, if not how do you calculate it's width including the text spacing and the width of a white space.

P.S. - Before flagging this question, do know I've went through most of the questions and answers and none of them were satisfactory.

Comment: Is using [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) an option?

Comment: @Scott I'm not using canvas. The text is in a `div`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate width and height of each character in a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408162/how-to-calculate-width-and-height-of-each-character-in-a-span)

Answer (score 0):

One way I would do it is to check if there's enough space left in the div. To do this, you would need to create an identical div and slowly remove one character from the cloned div until the original div is bigger or equal in width to the cloned div.

```
divClone.textContent = text
document.body.appendChild(divClone)
while(divClone.clientHeight > originalDiv.clientHeight) {
    divClone.textContent = divClone.textContent.substring(0, divClone.textContent.length-1)
}
originalDiv.textContent = divClone.textContent
```

You can then delete the cloned div when it's done